# Loop in python which appends answers to a list, I want to then create new list from this

Tags: python, list, append, qutip

This is the part of my code which works fine;

```
#taking time average
average= sum(result.expect[0])/len(t)
averagelist=[]
averagelist.append([num-Delta, average])
print(averagelist)
```

Giving output;

```
[[-50, 0.99994894092412567]]
[[-45, 0.9999371327219414]]
[[-40, 0.99992064521708557]]
[[-35, 0.99989662709502258]]
[[-30, 0.99985966374414359]]
[[-25, 0.99979843838324323]]
[[-20, 0.99968609192147129]]
[[-15, 0.99944283644552467]]
[[-10, 0.99874864586107459]]
[[-5, 0.99499296595818931]]
[[0, 0.50250021597634276]]
```

Now I want to be able to make a new list x= -50,-45,-40 etc
and new list y= 0.999..., 0.999..., 0.999... etc
Is there a simple way to do this?
(I have also tried the extend as oppose to append function, and this gives me the same initial output but with one square bracket not two.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this :

```
list_x = [i[0] for i in averagelist]
list_y = [i[1] for i in averagelist]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do something similar suggesting list_x= averagelist[0] but this didn't work. Thanks though this works perfectly!

Comment: Glad It helped =) Could you mark the post as answered ?